# Apps on SD showing as not installed, phone is constantly rebooting

Tags: app2sd

I've had the apps on SD card not showing issue a few times, but in the last few days anytime I use the stock camera app no apps show on the screen and when rebooting I get "no service", "service disabled" and the apps on the SD card show as not installed. My phone is now rebooting and in a reboot loop until I pull the battery.

Phone LS470 running 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Boot into recovery and clear Cache and Dalvik-Cache, if you are rooted. If not then search about how you can boot into stock recovery and then clear Cache and Dalvik-Cache.

Answer (score 0):

it can simply remove by opening phone in safe mode_______ or u may have deleted residual file of that application from sd card...

Comment: Please explain how to enter Safe Mode.